# Using Python, Tweepy, Insert Cursor and Arcpy

Tags: python, insert, cursor, tweepy, arcpy

I am super new to Python so forgive me for my lack of knowledge haha but for some reason I cannot get Python to insert rows in my database. Here is what I have:

```
import sys, arcpy, datetime, tweepy


consumer_key = " "
consumer_secret = " "
access_token = " "
access_token_secret = " "

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

table = r"C:\....dbf"

rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(table)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:


            user = status.user.screen_name
            tweet = status.text
            coord_x = status.coordinates['coordinates'][0]
            coord_y = status.coordinates['coordinates'][1]
            date_utc = status.created_at
            h_m_s_utc = (str(status.created_at.hour))+':'+(str(status.created_at.minute))+':'+(str(status.created_at.second))
            date_est = datetime.datetime.now()
            h_m_s_est = (str(date_est.hour))+':'+(str(date_est.minute))+':'+(str(date_est.second))


            row.user_name=user
            row.tweet=tweet
            row.coord_x=coord_x
            row.coord_y=coord_y
            row.date_utc=date_utc
            row.h_m_s_utc=h_m_s_utc
            row.date_est=date_est
            rows.insertRow(row)
            del row, rows
            insert_table= r"C:\....dbf"
            insert_row(insert_table)

        print user
        print tweet

    except:
        # If there are no coordinates for a tweet, then pass
        pass

def on_error(self, status_code):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
    return True # Don't kill the stream

def on_timeout(self):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
    return True # Don't kill the stream

# ----------------Script execution----------------
listener = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
listener.filter(track=[' love ', '#love'])
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the row.rowID thing.

Sorry if it is a disaster! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a traceback off your error?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you're forgetting to call the data access (.da) method for the insert cursor.

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(in_table, field_names) as inCursor:
    for row in rows:
        inCursor.insertRow(row) # example
```

-or-

```
inCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(in_table, field_names)
for row in rows:
    cursor.insertRow(row) # example
del inCursor # make sure to delete cursor if you do it this way as to avoid data lock.
```

Also, if you just want the Insert Cursor method, you can

```
from arcpy import da
```

For more info, check out:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w0000000t000000